# Merging and cleaning up csv files in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have been using pandas but am open to all suggestions, I'm not an expert at scripting but am a complete loss. My goal is the following:

- Merge multiple CSV files. Was able to do this in Pandas and have a dataframe with the merged dataset.

[Screenshot of how merged dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtHx8.png)

- Delete the duplicated "GEO" columns after the first set. This last part doesn't let me use`df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]` because they are not technically duplicated.The repeated column names end with a .1,.2,etc. as I am guessing the concate adds this. Other problem is that some columns have a duplicated column name but are different datasets. I have been using the first row as the index since it's always the same coded values but this row is unnecessary and will be deleted afterwards in the script. This is my biggest problem right now.
- Delete certain columns such as the ones with the "Margins". I use `~df2.columns.str.startswith` for this and have no trouble with this.
- Replace spaces, ":" and ";" with underscores in the first row. I have no clue how to do this.
- Insert a new column, write '=TEXT(B1,0)' formula, do this for the whole column (formula would change to B2,B3, etc.), copy the column and paste as values. I was able to do this in openpyxl although was having trouble and was not able to try the final output thanks to excel trouble. 
  `source = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
      excel.Range("C1:C1337").Select()
      excel.Selection.Copy()
      excel.Selection.PasteSpecial(Paste=constants.xlPasteValues)` 
  Not sure if it works and was wondering if it was possible in pandas, win32com or I should stay with openpyxl. Thanks all!

Comment: Can you please paste the data as text values instead of an image?

Comment: It looks like some of these problems may be caused by the way you are merging the data frames. You might back-track to there to solve the issues.

Comment: Thank you @Nathaniel I was able to shorten the code and get the dataframe without .1,.2 at the end. Unfortunately when using `df = result.columns.duplicated(['Col.id','Col.id2'],keep='first)`  I get the following error: TypeError: duplicated() got multiple values for keyword argument 'keep'. Works fine with the `str.startswith()`. But that would delete the first instance of the 'Col.id' which I dont want to do. I tried deleting the 'keep=' but get this error ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False.

Comment: Glad to hear you are making progress. If you'd like to get some help here, please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which includes example data in text form, the code required to demonstrate the problem, and a description of the desired output. Without this it is difficult to provide useful feedback. It may be helpful to post multiple specific questions and keep the focus on a single issue for each.